# Apache failed to bind port 80

Tags: apache, port80

hai friends i was trying to run apache server in my windows10 system but it fails as it was used by some other process.I ran netstat -nao | find ":80" command and it says pid 1900.But I cant find the process with pid 1900 in the task manager.What should i do.?Please help me as i'm a beginner.

Comment: opening `http://127.0.0.1` may provide some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have a similar issue with tomcat8.
If i restart server everything works fine. If restart tomcat service the ports seem busy.
I'm testing it but i'm pretty sure that should be related with some recent microsoft update, because 2 days ago there's any problem.
I'm tryng to uninstall last updates but i'm in a production server and it's not easy to reboot every time.
Can you test it?
Stay tuned
regards